# Conditional information extraction

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an issue extracting data from from cells.

As you can see here, I have two kinds of information:

[image: Data Example]

In first cell you can see that I need to extract information from within brackets. For that i use this command:

```
=MID(Informacija!K2;FIND("[";Informacija!K2)+1;FIND("]";Informacija!K2)-FIND("[";Informacija!K2)-1)
```

The main problem that I can't resolve how to combine two actions as follows:

If there are brackets in the cell, then take information from there, but if there are not brackets then just copy whole information from the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIND()` returns a `#VALUE!` error if the text is not found, so we can use `IFERROR()` to simply return the entire cell if no brackets are found.

```
=IFERROR(MID(Informacija!K2;FIND("[";Informacija!K2)+1;FIND("]";Informacija!K2)-FIND("[";Informacija!K2)-1);Informacija!K2)
```

Comment: it does not work. Do i understand your code correctly? It will copy whole cell information if it gets #value error, but if it doesn't it will copy information from brackets?

Comment: @Username I edited my post, try it now. I used a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: i noticed that, but instead of showing information, it shows 0.

Comment: I found the problem. That k2 was from another sheet. So i needed to show the path. Thank you Kyle